# Angular xeditable disable the form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable, angular-xeditable

I am using the angular directive: http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

And I am trying to get the form displayed as a disabled form, I mean, with all the element disabled (disabled html attribute).

I saw that there is a flag of the form, `$waiting` set by `$setWaiting()`, that behaves like that, but there aren't a way to invoke this status as the `$show()`.

There is a way to access to that method from my controller? or in the other hand, how i can extend the directive to make this method public.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a late answer, but as no one has answered this...

I think to mess with the `$waiting` attribute could get you in more trouble that help, as it handles the state of submitting and who know what else.

The easiest way to accomplish disabling the form-elements is to just use the `e-ng-disabled` attribute of each editable-control bound to a `$scope` variable like this:

```
<span editable-text="my_model" e-name="name" 
    e-ng-disabled="form_disabled">{{ my_model }}</span>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jf2ykddv/5/

Just for the record, of course it would be nice to be able to disable all controls with some kind of "global" attribute directly through the form, but I don't think thats implemented in angular-xeditable. So this is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Only add property in your tag.

```
e-ng-disabled="[value]"
```